# Daemonizing a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need a script to behave as as if executed by `/.a.sh &`, even though I leave out the `&`.  Is there a more elegant way of doing this than wrapping the whole script in `{ .. } &`?

Comment: Please tell us what you have done until now and how we may help you complete your script.

Comment: That's not dæmonization.   That's running in parallel in the background.